# BeautifulSoup4 with lxml xml parser removes xmlns attributes from inline svg in xhtml file

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xhtml, lxml

I have BeautifulSoup4 v4.6.0 and lxml v3.8.0 installed. I am trying to parse the following `xhtml`.

My code to parse:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xhtml_string = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body class="sgc-1">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 600 800" width="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <image height="800" width="573" xlink:href="../Images/Cover.jpg"></image>
      </svg>
    </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xhtml_string, 'xml')
```

However when I inspect the soup, it appears that BeautifulSoup has stripped the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` and the `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` on the `<svg>` tag and `xlink` prefix on the `href` attribute on the `<image>` tag.

i.e. `soup.prettify()` returns the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="unicode-escape"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body class="sgc-1">
    <svg height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 600 800" width="100%">
      <image height="800" href="../Images/Cover.jpg" width="573"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do not have the option to change the source `xhtml` and from what I've seen the `xmlns` declarations are valid. Is there any way for to make BeautifulSoup preserve the `xhtml` as is?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lxml` parser instead of the `xml`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xhtml_string, 'lxml')
```

Comment: On the other hand, lxml parser does not preserve case (so tags are all turned lowercase). Is there a parser, or an option in lxml to preserve case to have full solution?

Comment: You can try html5 parser